# How to Access AVStream Extended Camera Control Properties in user mode app C++

Tags: c++, drivers, ms-media-foundation

I'm looking for the API in Media foundation to access the extended camera controls
[Extended Camera Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj733424(v=vs.85).aspx)

for example photomode  evcompensation etc. 
is there anything similar to the standard interfaces IAMCameraControl , IAMVideoProcAmp
if not what is the standard way to access - set or query these controls?

Answer (score 1):

There is not common design to access this properties inside MediaFoundation.

In fact, it's up to the manufacturer and his driver, to provide these interfaces or some kind of attributes.

- for attributes, as you can see here : [Capture Device Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317915(v=vs.85).aspx), it is poor designed to access all capture characteristic. You can ask to each manufacturer if they provide some specific attributes.
- for interfaces (IAMCameraControl, IAMVideoProcAmp), you can try to query through the media capture source (do a QueryInterface on IMFMediaSource). Once again, it's up to the manufacturer.